# Fast PDF generation library for .net core (C#)

Tags: library, pdf, c#, .net, pdf-generation

Could you recommend me a PDF library for .net core (C#)?

I need to generate a simple pdf with standalone text and some images.

Performance is the key value. Sometimes I'll generate around 150 k separate pdf files per hour. Any advice?

Comment: Are you open to how you will layout the content? Or do you have a preference? Such as HTML or Markdown for your layout? Is this a new feature? If not, what issues do you have with your existing solution?

Answer (score 2):

Syncfusion Essential PDF is a feature rich and high-performance [.NET Core PDF library](https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/net-core) that allows you to add robust PDF functionalities to any ASP.NET Core applications. It allows you to create, read, and edit PDF documents programmatically. This library also offers functionality to merge, split, stamp, forms, and secure PDF files.

Syncfusion Essential PDF comes with extensive [documentation](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/overview), [Knowledge Base](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/windowsforms/pdf?tab=newest&tags=pdf), and [samples](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/PDF/Default#/material).

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Answer (score 1):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) is a good option. It is fast, has no external dependencies, fully managed code, works in .NET and .NET Standard / .NET Core.

Disclaimer: I work for the company.

Here are examples for your tasks:

- [Draw text](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Text/DrawText)
- [Add and draw images](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Images/AddAndDrawImage)

Answer (score 0):

[XFINIUM.PDF](https://xfiniumpdf.com) library supports .NET Core and it is fast. My opinion could be biased as I work for the company that develops the library.

xfinium.pdf.netcore package is available on nuget.org. Several samples are available on our website.

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you noted your performance requirements.  150k documents per hour averages at 42 documents/second which may result in significant load on the host.  Bear that in mind for whatever tool you are using and what else your server/host is doing.

[Docmosis Tornado](https://www.docmosis.com/products/tornado.html) or [Docmosis Cloud](https://www.docmosis.com/products/cloud.html) may be a good fit depending on your other requirements around connectivity, privacy etc.  Please note I work for Docmosis.  Either will let you scale to be able to achieve the performance required and the main bonus is that you can use document templates to design the output.  This means the coding required is reduced to composing the data and making the http(s) calls.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [itext7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/), which provides various features to do with PDF. It also have document and examples for common uses.

Comment: Welcome! Does this recommendation meet the performance requirements?